# Listening to URL changes of an angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, angular-routing

I have an application which contains an `iframe`, the `iframe` is rendering an angular 4 application.
I tried to listen to the `iframe`'s URL in the following way:

```
frame.src = appSource;
    frame.addEventListener('load', function () {
        frame.contentWindow.window.sdk = frame.contentWindow.window.sdk || sdk;
        frame.contentWindow.window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => console.log('url changed!!!'), true);
    }, true);
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't see the `console.log` message.
The angular application (which is inside the `iframe`) is using the angular router to navigate between pages, using a code like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/page']);
```

Moreover, the angular application uses `useHash: true` in its `RouterModule`:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: AppCustomPreloader })
```

I tried to replace it with `useHash: false` and change the event listener to `onpushstate`, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Any idea how can I listen to the URL changes of the angular app?

Comment: Have you ever gone through this: https://angular.io/guide/router#routing--navigation

Comment: The main application which listens to the iframe's url is not an angular application, so I can't listen to the url change via the angular Router.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Angular navigation events: https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events

Eg. you could call window.postMessage on NavigationEnd in Angular and listen to that in the parent frame. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Ie. there's no way to detect a hash change or a history push from outside the frame but postMessage is a safe way to communicate between frames.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I don't want to listen to the url change inside my angular application, because I have multiple iframes, each iframe is a different application, and I don't want to repeat on the url listening code in each application, I want this to be only in one place, which is my root application which creates and holds all the iframes.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no other way but postMessage, because a load event triggers only once with an ng app, when it's first loaded, and due to security you cannot access anything in a frame that'd allow listening to hash or history changes.

Comment: If you don't want to change the ng apps, can you inject a simple script file into the index.html of all the ng apps? In it you can listen to hash or push changes and do the postMessage calling. ie. copy paste solution

Comment: The root application and the child-applications are under the same domain, so there is no security issue, I can listen to those events, and when I tried to navigate inside the angular app without angular router, it did raise the hashchange event. Just with the Angular Router, for a reason I don't understand, it doesn't raise the hashchange event.

Comment: ah, sounds like the ng router calls preventDefault etc on it.

Comment: I'd still go postMessage way. You can make a service that listens to navigationEnd and hits postMessage, and reuse that across apps :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess that this is the only alternative if we'll keep using the angular router, thanks! :)